# AJAX function not being called with button onclick function

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, servlets

I have a simple form with 2 input fields and one button.  When the button is clicked, the value of the 2 input fields should be sent to the AJAX function to be handled in a servlet.  For some reason, the servlet is not being reached.  Can anyone see why?  I have an almost identical method working with a different form, and I can't see why this one isn't working.

Here is the HTML form code:

```
     <div id="addCourses" class="hidden" align="center" >
        <form id="addCourse" name="addCourse">
        <input type="text" id="courseID" name="courseID" value="courseID" size="40" /><br />
        <textarea rows="5" cols="33" id="courseDesc" name="courseDesc">Description</textarea><br />
        <input type="button" value="Add Course" onclick="addCourse(this.courseID.value, this.courseDesc.value);"/>
        </form>
    </div>
```

Here is the Script function:

```
<script type ="text/javascript">
function addCourse(id, descr)
{
   var fluffy;
   fluffy=new XMLHttpRequest();
   fluffy.onreadystatechange=function()
   {
      if (fluffy.readyState==4 && fluffy.status==200)
      {   
      //do something here
      }  
   };

  fluffy.open("GET","ajaxServlet?courseID="+id+"&courseDescription="+descr,true);
  fluffy.send();
}
</script>
```

Comment: You should install Firebug or something similar to intercept javascript errors.

Comment: What is your error? Did you check your browser's console for some hints?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Ghigo.  I will install Firebug.  I am new to javascript, so this will be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `this` is the button and not the form

so

```
this.courseID.value
this.courseDesc.value
```

returns an error.

You should use

```
this.form.courseID.value
this.form.courseDesc.value
```

Second problem is you have a name clash. The form and function are named addCourse. It will lead to problems. Rename one of them to be different.

[Running Example](http://jsfiddle.net/sz8A5/)

Comment: Thank you epascarello.  I have fixed both of these problems.  I have used your suggestions along with @jbabey's suggestions and now it is working.  I am new to html, javascript, and ajax.

Answer (score 1):

When you use `this`, as in `onclick="addCourse(this.courseID.value, this.courseDesc.value);"`, I think that would refer to the `input` element, and therefore the values aren't being passed correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Bind your event handlers in javascript, where they should be, and you can avoid the issue entirely.

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="courseID" name="courseID" value="courseID" size="40" /><br />
<textarea rows="5" cols="33" id="courseDesc" name="courseDesc">Description</textarea><br />
<input type="button" id="addCourse" value="Add Course"/>
```

JS:

```
document.getElementById('addCourse').onclick = function () {
    var fluffy = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var id = document.getElementById('courseID').value;
    var descr = document.getElementById('courseDesc').value;

    fluffy.onreadystatechange=function() {
        if (fluffy.readyState==4 && fluffy.status==200) {   
            //do something here
        }  
    };

    fluffy.open("GET","ajaxServlet?courseID="+id+"&courseDescription="+descr,true);
    fluffy.send();
};
```

As epascarello pointed out, you need to change the ID of your form as having two elements with the same ID is not allowed and will cause unpredictable javascript behavior.

Comment: I haven't been able to get the function to call without the "onclick=addCourse()" in the button definition itself, but I would like to figure out why.  I did however, change the function so that it doesn't accept parameters, and I am getting the values of id and descr inside the function as you have suggested.  Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try a fluffy.close; after the if ready state expression.